# Scanning multiple pages via document feeder with WIA

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, wia

Having a problem getting this working after following some samples and checking ways to fix this error with other questions posted on here, nothing working so far.

It scans the first page and when the code loops around to where it should get the second image it always throws exception saying the device is busy, is there anyway to pause or stop the scanning in document feeder after each page to prevent this exception?

```
string deviceid;
List<ImageFile> images = new List<ImageFile>();

CommonDialogClass dlg = new CommonDialogClass();
Device d = dlg.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true, false);
if (d != null)
{
    deviceid = d.DeviceID;
}
else
{
    //no scanner chosen
    return;
}

bool hasMorePages = true;
int x = 0;
int numPages = 0;
while (hasMorePages)
{
    DeviceManager manager = new DeviceManagerClass();
    Device WiaDev = null;
    foreach (DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
    {
        if (info.DeviceID == deviceid)
        {
            WIA.Properties infoprop = null;
            infoprop = info.Properties;
            WiaDev = info.Connect();
            break;
        }
    }
    SelectDeviceDocumentHandling(WiaDev, DeviceDocumentHandling.Feeder);
    SetDeviceProperty(WiaDev, DEVICE_PROPERTY_PAGES_ID, 1);
    
    ImageFile img = null;
    Item Item = WiaDev.Items[1];
    try
    {
        WIA.CommonDialog WiaCommonDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
        img = (ImageFile)WiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(Item, FormatID.wiaFormatPNG, false);
        images.Add(img);
        numPages++;
        img = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //ex.Message "0x80210003" means no documents found in feeder
    {
        if (ex.Message.Contains("0x80210015")) MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to scanner", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        else if (ex.Message.Contains("0x80210006")) MessageBox.Show("Device is busy", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); //where I get exception on second page each time
        else if (ex.Message.Contains("0x80210003")) MessageBox.Show("No documents found in document feeder", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        else MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        Item = null;
        //determine if there are any more pages waiting
        Property documentHandlingSelect = null;
        Property documentHandlingStatus = null;

        foreach (Property prop in WiaDev.Properties)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyID == WIA_PROPERTIES.WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT)
                documentHandlingSelect = prop;
            if (prop.PropertyID == WIA_PROPERTIES.WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS)
                documentHandlingStatus = prop;
        }
        hasMorePages = false; //assume there are no more pages
        if (documentHandlingSelect != null)
        //may not exist on flatbed scanner but required for feeder
        {
            //check for document feeder
            if ((Convert.ToUInt32(documentHandlingSelect.get_Value()) & WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT.FEEDER) != 0)
            {
                hasMorePages = ((Convert.ToUInt32(documentHandlingStatus.get_Value()) & WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS.FEED_READY) != 0);
            }
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

I've tried solutions from the following post with no luck, as well as searching around the web a lot:
[Scanning with WIA automatic feeder scanner fails for second page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708547/scanning-with-wia-automatic-feeder-scanner-fails-for-second-page)

Wondering if this might also be a problem with my specific scanner, I'm working from home but will be able to test on work scanner when back in office next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it's when the program connects to a scanner using WSD for some reason. When I connect via USB cable I don't get this problem as then it uses the manufacturer's driver instead.