# Exception From Wia Scanner

Tags: c#, wia

I am using WIA to connect to a scanner. I enumerate the device Infos and then try connecting to the device. I keep getting the exception.

Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070021

```
WIA.DeviceManager manager = new WIA.DeviceManager();
WIA.Device device = null;
foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
{
// connect to scanner
 device = info.Connect();
 break;
}
```

Exception message is: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070021)

My Scanner machine not connected. I got error "access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070021)"

But Individually Scan working fine. when i try to connect with coding i get error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WIA Image Scanning fails with HRESULT: 0x80070050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121151/c-sharp-wia-image-scanning-fails-with-hresult-0x80070050)

Comment: No. My issue is not connected scanner. Getting Error in info.Connect() line